# Instalar proyecto PHP Storm en local en Windows10

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

Yo trabajo en Mac (macOS Catalina) tengo un proyecto desarrollado en Laravel 7 (con PHP Storm) en mi máquina funciona perfectamente, lo he migrado a dos servidores, demo y pro, y funciona correctamente. En el cliente trabajan con Windows10 y cuando migramos el proyecto para que trabajen en local no funciona, me dan errores de PHP simples, tipo no reconoce un foreach, hemos realizado un montón de pruebas, hemos probado con php 7.3 y 7.4 y probado diferentes configuraciones de php.ini pero nada tenemos el error todo el rato.

He revisado la configuración de mi PHP Storm y copiado hasta el más ínfimo detalle en la máquina con Windows10 y sigue fallando, la verdad que no tengo ni idea de por donde seguir, si alguien puede ayudarme estaré muy agradecido.

Conseguimos arrancar el PHP artisan serve (servidor local de Laravel) carga la home de la aplicación y hace el login, pero cuando navego a la parte del aplicativo obtengo los errores de laravel...

Adjunto imagen del error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es probable que tengas algún problema con la configuración de php.ini, algún módulo que tengas en las otras máquinas y que no estén presentes por defecto en el apacha/php que usas en windows. Te recomiendo mirar docker y dockerizar tu app, nunca más tendrás problemas de este tipo

Comment: La verdad no tengo ni idea de Docker y no se que implicación de tiempo podría llevar esta solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo pude resolver, todo se debía a la versión PHP que había instalado en mi máquina, estaba usando la descargada desde la web de php.net y no funcionaba, probé a descargar XAMPP y sustituir los archivos de la carpeta PHP por los que trae XAMPP y todo arreglado, no entiendo bien la diferencia de una versión y otra y por qué la de la web oficial no es completa...